# Plugin dependencies: show notice like theme plugins dependencies

Tags: plugins, admin

I've developed a plugin that its core doesn't rely on any external plugin but there is some functionality that can be unlocked if others plugins are active. What I would like to achieve is to display an admin notice to offer the user to install those plugins, but I would like to do it as themes plugin dependency does, with the begin installing plugins functionality, something like this:

[image]

Could this be done with plugins or is it limited to themes?

I know I could do a custom admin notice, but I need to do it as easiest as I could for wordpress administrators, as theme does.

Thanks

Comment: I think a custom admin notice is the easiest bet. It's literally just a few lines of code.  The 'install dependent plugins' link could be something like http://.../wp-admin/plugin-install.php?s=yourname&tab=search&type=author if you are the author of the dependent plugins, or use a tab, or keyword?  Look at the code for the example you gave and see how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a list of services and open sources that might be useful:

- [WP Package Editor](https://wordpress.recuweb.com/)

> WP2E is a service allowing developers to create and manage installation
> packages to deliver and maintain sets of interdependent themes and
> plugins.

- [WPFavs](https://wpfavs.com/)

> It is a Free WordPress plugin manager and bulk installation tool

- [WordPress Packagist](https://wpackagist.org/)

> This site mirrors the WordPress plugin and theme directories as a
> Composer repository.

- [WP Plugin Dependencies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-dependencies/)

> This meta-plugin allows regular plugins to specify other plugins that
> they depend upon.

- [WP Dependency Installer](https://github.com/afragen/wp-dependency-installer)

> A lightweight class to add to WordPress plugins/themes to
> automatically install plugin dependencies.